# How to make a random choice and use it later to display images (python 3)?

Tags: python, random, display

```
import random 
foo = ['battery', 'correct', 'horse', 'staple']
secure_random = random.SystemRandom() 
print(secure_random.choice(foo)) 
if foo == "battery" : 
    print ("a") 
if foo == "correct" : 
    print ("a") 
if foo == "horse" :
    print ("a")
if foo == "staple" : 
   print ("a")
```

Comment: `foo` is a list... Do you expect any of these if statements to be entered? If so, why?

Comment: just store the result before you print it and use it later, what could be simpler?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than repeat the same thing in if statements, make a list of tuples to join the "images" with their value

```
foo = [('battery', battery_img), ( 'correct', correct_img)]
```

Take a random tuple, and show the image

```
value, img = random.choice(foo) 
print("Show {} for value {}".format(img, value))
```